# Rank score in summary-features

Tags: rank, summary, vespa

Looking for a way to always have the executed rank profile score as part of the summary (rather than configure it explicitly for each new rank profile (by adding the function used under summary-features))
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in one rank profile and inherit it in the others:

```
rank-profile parent {
    summary-features {
        firstPhase
    }
}

rank-profile child1 inherits parent {
    # Will have firstPhase as summary feature
}

rank-profile child2 inherits parent {
    # If the child defines its own features it must inherit the parents explicitly
    summary-features inherits parent {
        ....
    }
}
```